# Extract number between brackets in Excel?

Tags: excel, extract, brackets

I've been searching up and down for an answer to this, but haven't found anything I can get to work. It may well be my lack of knowledge in the more "codey" aspects of Excel.

Anyway, this is my situation:
In C2-C17, I have some text set up like this:[2] Name of job.
The "[2]" indicates the hours we expect the assignment to take, the rest is the name of the assignment.

Now I need to calculate how many hours all this adds up to, so in B2-B17 (the numbers will change) I would like to extract the number between the brackets, in this case "2", so I can simply calculate and add them up.

How would I go about doing this? I've spent far too long at work by now, trying to find a solution that works for me.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 15):

Use the formulas:  `MID(cell,start_num, length)` and  `FIND(text,cell)`

So, the formula is:

```
=MID(B3, FIND("[",B3)+1, FIND("]",B3) - FIND("[",B3) - 1)
```

Which means:
  Extract the text from the cell B3, starting from the location of character "[" plus 1 in the same cell, and a total of chars calculates by:  location of "]" - location of "[" minus one.

Answer (score 0):

Copy to a new column, Find & Replace, Find what:

```
*[
```

Replace All. Find what:

```
]*
```

Replace All.

Comment: Would have liked a formula that I could just copy/paste, but as a backup option, this works too, thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a function to work with substrings: "MID"

[image]

The C3 cell have formula. We assume that string will always start from [ and then will be number of hours (1 digit).

[image]

Than I just expand to other cells froc C3 to F3

You can add substitute function to work with two digit numbers.

[image]

Comment: With a few minor corrections, I got that to work, thank you!

But I should have been more specific (I didn't think it mattered in the way this was done):

Some times the number will be 2,5, or 3,25 and so forth, so I need to extract the entire number between brackets, and the character-length of that number can vary. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Ok, I got it. Yes there is a way to catch dynamically length and place. It is described in other answer by @Necho

Comment: =MID(B3, FIND("[",B3)+1, FIND("]",B3) - FIND("[",B3) - 1)

Comment: @PhilipAskZeplin-Frederiksen so don't hestate to vote for my answer! (arrow up) and approve it