# Split a text in excel containing text and number in brackets

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula

I want to split a cell into multiple columns with each own.
Please see below for example.

```
Currrent Cell:
Mobile Users (300)
Want to Split into two more cells:
Device Category        Number of Users
Mobile Users           300
```

I have used LEFT formula to separate Mobile Users one but cannot split 300 number successfully out of brackets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract number between brackets in Excel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28960349/extract-number-between-brackets-in-excel)

Comment: If you had actually shown the '*LEFT formula to separate Mobile Users*' formula you 'used' this would have been a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have the content (you wish to split) in cell `A3` the following formulas should work.

In cell `B4` to get `Mobile Users`:

```
=LEFT(A3,FIND("(",A3)-2)
```

In cell `C4` to get the number 300 from within the brackets:

```
=VALUE(MID(A3,FIND("(",A3)+1,FIND(")",A3)-FIND("(",A3)-1))
```

Comment: Bonus for getting the true number out of text-that-looks-like-a-number.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In B2 and C2,

```
=TRIM(LEFT(A2, FIND("(", A2)-1))
=--REPLACE(REPLACE(A2, FIND(")", A2), LEN(A2), TEXT(, )), 1, FIND("(", A2), TEXT(, ))
```

Don't play with text-that-look-like-numbers. Whenever possible, convert the text to a true number with the VALUE function or a **double-unary** (aka double minus or `--`).

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to get numbers only.

```
Function GetNums(target As Range)
    Dim MyStr As String, i As Integer
    MyStr = ""
    If Len(target.Value) = 0 Then GoTo GoExit
    If target.Value = "None" Then GoTo GoNone
    For i = 1 To Len(target.Value)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(target, i, 1)) Then MyStr = MyStr & Mid(target, i, 1)
    Next i
    GoTo GoExit
GoNone:
    GetNums = "None"
    Exit Function
GoExit:
    GetNums = MyStr

End Function
```